# I can not cd "LaunchAgents" on macbook

Tags: mac, installation

After installing mongdb on my macbook-pro, it tells me:

> If this is your first install,
>   automatically load on login with:
>
> ```
> cp /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/1.6.3-x86_64/org.mongodb.mongod.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
> launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.mongodb.mongod.plist
> ```
>
> If this is an upgrade and you already
>   have the org.mongodb.mongod.plist
>   loaded:
>
> ```
> launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.mongodb.mongod.plist
> cp /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/1.6.3-x86_64/org.mongodb.mongod.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
> launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.mongodb.mongod.plist
> ```
>
> Or start it manually:
>
> ```
> mongod run --config /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/1.6.3-x86_64/mongod.conf
> ```

But after I copy `org.mongodb.mongod.plist` to `~/Library/LaunchAgents`, it tells me:

```
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.mongodb.mongod.plist
launchctl: Couldn't stat("/Users/why/Library/LaunchAgents/org.mongodb.mongod.plist"):
Not a directory
```

And also I can not `cd "~/Library/LaunchAgents"`, but I can `ls` the directory!

`~/Library/LaunchAgents` is a strange directory on mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you make sure that you created the `~/Library/LaunchAgents` directory first? You may have just ended up copying `/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/1.6.3-x86_64/org.mongodb.mongod.plist` to a *file* called `~/Library/LaunchAgents`

Try `ls -la ~/Library/LaunchAgents` and see what the output is. It should look like:

```
[why@why ~]$ ls -la ~/Library/LaunchAgents
total 40
drwxr-xr-x   7 why  why   238 Jan 11 09:47 .
drwx------+ 68 why  why  2312 Sep 28 19:39 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 why  why   543 Jan 11 09:47 org.mongodb.mongod.plist
```

If instead you see:

```
[why@why ~]$ ls -la ~/Library/LaunchAgents 
-rw-r--r--  1 why  why  543 Jan 11 09:47 /Users/why/Library/LaunchAgents
```

Then you copied the MongoDB plist to a file called `LaunchAgents`. Here's how to remedy that:

```
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents
mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents
cp /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/1.6.3-x86_64/org.mongodb.mongod.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.mongodb.mongod.plist
```

Comment: Good idea.  I usually append a / if I want to be sure of copying to a directory - i.e. `copy file dir/` then if `dir` doesn't exist, it wont copy `file` to a file called called `dir`